# multilevel delegates alternative

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

I have three classes class1, class2 and class3. Class2 is the child of class1 and class3 is child of class2. I currently have a delegate in class2 and class3. To communicate from class 3 to class1 class 3 makes a delegate call to class2 and class 2 makes a delegate call to class1.

Is there any efficient approach.

Thanks

Comment: [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Nsnotification center broadcasts message right. I am don't want to broadcast message to all the classes.

Comment: You can make a call from class3 to class1 delegate, it is direct approach. while having delegate of class2 in class3, you can also have delegate of class1 in class3

Comment: @AsifHabib can you be more specific.

Comment: With notification center, you only broadcast to objects are listening. (Which you have to specify)

Comment: Have you consider using blocks? You have explained a generic case case. If a event occurs in class 3 and there are set of instructions to be executed of class 1, you can use blocks

Comment: I will go wit @iCoder try out blocks easy and simple to use for callbacks.

Comment: When I have to communicate a class I save its delegate globally and then make a call to that delegate. Your question is in theory and I answered it in theory, if you have shared a little code, I can explain you how to do that.

Comment: Apart from the solutions suggested here, the pattern you are describing sounds a bit odd. That is, the idea that you are having delegates directly up the polymorphism chain. Sharing code is always preferable to describing stuff like this in an abstract manner as it might help us to help you a lot better than simply commenting in a general manner.